# Sitecore 8.1 error: "No session Id managers were found to manage the session Id for the current request"

Tags: mongodb, session, sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-fxm

I'm attempting to get a basic layout up and running in Sitecore 8.1, and I've hit an error about which I can find very little information. When attempting to view any page (even the backend interface or connecting from Sitecore Rocks), I get the message "No session Id managers were found to manage the session Id for the current request."

Some Googling suggests that this has to do with some issues with the out-of-box session provider and recommends swapping it out for keeping the sessions in Mongo. Sitecore's documentation provides a description of this, both for [shared](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/xdb%20configuration/walkthrough%20configuring%20a%20shared%20session%20state%20database%20using%20the%20mongodb%20provider) and [private](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/xdb_configuration/walkthrough_configuring_a_private_session_state_database_using_the_mongodb_provider) sessions. I've attempted to implement those but continue to receive the same error.

Here's my code as it stands now:

**App_Config/Include/MongoSessionProvider.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <tracking>
      <sharedSessionState>
        <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="mongo" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB" connectionString="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" sessionType="shared"/>
        </providers>
      </sharedSessionState>
    </tracking>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**App_Config/Include/ConnectionStrings.config (excerpt)**

```xml
<add name="session" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/sharedsession" />
```

**Web.config (excerpt)**

```xml
<sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="false" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.FXM.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager" customProvider="mongo">
  <providers>
    <add name="mongo" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
    <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Note that this is on my local development machine. I have Mongo running (and confirmed its connection to Sitecore), and I created both the session and sharedsession databases in it using `use session` and `use sharedsession`, which I understand to be the way to create DBs in Mongo.

Am I missing something here? Or does the error simply not mean what I think it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else, we were running into this issue as well after upgrading to Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151003.

In our particular case the issue was with a namespace change in this line in the **Web.config**:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"
 sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.FXM.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager">
```

That should be the following:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"
 sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager">
```

It might have been something we missed in the upgrade guide, but we finall found it after pulling down the a copy of **Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151003.zip** from [the downloads page](https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/Sitecore_81/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_81_Initial_Release.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

The message you are seeing is not supposed to be an error, it is rather a log warning. It is related to retrieving the configuration of the Session ID Manager rather that to the configuration of the session itself.

## Why this warning normally appears

In the ***Sitecore.config*** under `<pipelines>` there's the `getSessionIdManager` pipeline defined.

```xml
<getSessionIdManager>
</getSessionIdManager>
```

In the ***Sitecore.FXM.config***, there is a processor configured for this pipeline:

```xml
<getSessionIdManager>
  <processor type="Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.ChooseSessionIdManager.FXMSessionIdManagerProcessor, Sitecore.FXM" />
</getSessionIdManager>
```

This pipeline allows to dynamically select a Session ID Manager for the request. In the default Sitecore configuration, a non-default Session ID Manager will be used only for requests with explicit `sessionId` URL parameter, i.e. for FXM requests only.

For all other requests, no Session ID Manager will be explicitly selected, and the default `System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager` will be used; this is reflected in the warning message you're seeing. There is nothing wrong with this situation per se, this is by default and by design.

## Seeing the message as an error on every page request

This definitely sounds like a defect to me. This message is supposed to be *logged* once per application lifetime instead of being thrown as an exception on every page.

You should report this to Sitecore support.

## An attempt to fix

I cannot debug your system, so I have to do this blindfolded. I would try to create you own Session ID Manager selector:

```csharp
public class CustomSessionIdManagerProcessor
{
    public void Process(GetSessionIdManagerArgs args)
    {
        if(args.SessionIdManager == null)
        {
            args.SessionIdManager = new System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager();
        }
    }
}
```

Configure it as the **last** processor in the `getSessionIdManager` pipeline. This will make sure that there is always an explicitly selected Session ID Manager and should hopefully prevent the error from happening.

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getSessionIdManager>
        <processor type="YourNamespace.CustomSessionIdManagerProcessor, YourAssembly" />
      </getSessionIdManager>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's not showing up as a warning, it's an exception that prevents anything from rendering (specifically a `Sitecore.Exceptions.ProviderConfigurationException`, if that's at all helpful). It actually doesn't show up in the logs at all, which is part of why I'm having so much trouble tracking it down. I'll try your temp fix and report back.

Comment: @MichaelSmith I misunderstood you about the error. Please provide a screenshot, or even better, the full stacktrace as a part of your question.
The message you're seeing is **really** supposed to be a log warning and nothing else: http://i.imgur.com/UH3W3yb.png

Comment: I think I've managed to resolve it, actually. I removed `sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.FXM.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager"`[1] from the `sessionState` node in web.config and the error went away. I'm now having another issue[2], though, and I'm trying to determine if it's unrelated or caused by my fix.

[1] I think I put that there while dealing with an earlier FXM-related issue.

[2] Currently nothing has a layout, not even the launchpad. Everything's looking for a layout with all zeroes as the GUID, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @MichaelSmith ha, yeah, `ConditionalSessionIdManage‌r` should not be used with anything but FXM session.

Comment: @MichaelSmith your second issue does not sound related to your session confiugration...

Comment: Yeah, I'm figuring probably not, but I hesitate on calling this fixed until I know for sure what's going on.

Comment: @MichaelSmith were you able to fix the issue eventually?

Comment: Yeah, we got it fixed. When I get a little spare time, I'll write up the details. Thanks for checking up on it.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Hi Michael, could you please share your solution how did you fixed it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MichaelSmith I'm curious if you've done a write up yet on the possible fix details?

Comment: @JamesSkemp The fix for this issue is what I mentioned above: removing the `sessionIDManagerType` attribute from the `sessionState` node. The other issue I was going to write up was unrelated (and at this point I don't even recall the details of it clearly). I probably should've put that as a separate answer so I could accept it, but yours seems more complete so I'll go with that instead.